# BATCH - Copiar N archivos de un directorio Windows

Tags: windows, batch, powershell

Estoy realizando un proceso para copiar distintos archivos de distintas carpetas, con la particularidad que preciso pasar, por ejemplo, 30 archivos de un directorio (que contiene más de 100). Los 30 que debo pasar, no importan cuales sean, deben ser 30.

Hice algo parecido a esto, acá lo uso para mostrar los nombres nomás:

```
set contador=0

FOR /R d:\Users\usuario\Desktop\1\ %%A IN (*) DO (
    IF %contador% LSS 3 (
    echo %%A
    echo %contador%        
    SET /a contador=contador+1
    )ELSE (
    EXIT
    )   
    )
```

Lo que sucedió fue que dentro del FOR, contador siempre fue "0". Si lo imprimía fuera del FOR, quedaba con el número correcto. Así que me di cuenta que no me sirve el criterio del FOR para cada archivo dentro del directorio (el *).

Cómo hago para limitarlo? para que recorra sólo 30 archivos y no todos los que están dentro de la carpeta?

Gracias y saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo utilizar **PowerShell**, no solamente porque es más simple y fácil, si no por todas las demás cosas que te va a proporcionar cuando empieces a utilizarlo (sintaxis, objetos, módulos, etxc).

Para lo que tu comentas se podría resolver de la siguiente manera:

```
#Variables
$cantidadArchivos = 3
$carpetaOrigen = 'C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Desktop\Origen\'
$carpetaDestino = 'C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Desktop\Destino\'
#Copia de los archivos
for ($i=0; $i -lt $cantidadArchivos; $i++) {
    Write-host "Copiando:" (Get-ChildItem $carpetaOrigen)[$i].FullName 
    Copy-Item (Get-ChildItem $carpetaOrigen)[$i].FullName -Destination $carpetaDestino
}
```

Ahí puedes definir en las primeras tres variables lo que necesitas (cantidad de archivos a copiar, origen y destino) y listo!

**Editado:**

En batch se realiza de la siguiente manera:

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Defino las variables
    set "origen=C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Desktop\Origen"
    set "destino=C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Desktop\Destino"
    set num=3

    rem Bloque de ejecución
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%f in ('dir /b /a "%origen%\*"  ^| findstr /n "^" ') do (
        if %%f leq %num% (
            echo Copiando: "%origen%\%%g"
            copy "%origen%\%%g" "%destino%" /y > nul 
        ) else goto fin
    )

:fin
    endlocal
```

Por más info, te recomiendo leer el siguiente enlace: [FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Comment: Hola Victor muchas gracias. Por una cuestión de permisos, es más complejo que usemos PowerShell. Existe alguna posibilidad de recrear algo similar en batch?

Comment: @Nico.C fijate si con eso podés hacer lo que requieres. Saludos

Comment: muchisimas gracias! funcionó bárbaro. Me quedan unas consultas luego de ver el enlace que proporcionaste (muy útil):

"tokens=1,2 delims=:"    En esto, para qué el delimitador en ":" y no entendí bien qué hace tokens.

^| findstr /n "^" '  buscás un salto de línea? y la primer barra para qué eso?

%%g es siempre el valor que varía dentro del for, si yo no hubiera usado %%f para mi ciclo, como identifico ese valor que va cambiando cuando sube el contador?

Saludoss!!

Comment: "tokens=1,2 delims=:" permite armar los 2 parámetros %%f y %%g; %%f es el "contador" y %%g el nombre del archivo a copiar. La barra ("|") permite enviar al siguiente comando la salida del anterior. Los valores %%f y %%g podrías reemplazarlos por %%h e %%i por ejemplo, sin problemas.